# NSMutableArray contains Some unknown data

Tags: iphone, ios5, xcode4

I've a NSMutableArray and I'm assigning object to it like `[appDelegate.array addObject:Obj];` when i call `NSLog(@"appdelegate.array %@ ", [appdelegate.array description]) ;` I'm getting like this in consol

```
(
    "<Item: 0x6c8b650; frame = (0 0; 0 0); transform = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]; alpha = 0; opaque = NO; layer = (null)>",
    "<Item: 0x6b825c0; frame = (0 0; 0 0); transform = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]; alpha = 0; opaque = NO; layer = (null)>",
    "<Item: 0x6b82ad0; frame = (0 0; 0 0); transform = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]; alpha = 0; opaque = NO; layer = (null)>"
)
```

Can any one suggest me to correct format to add objects and why array contains `frame = (0 0; 0 0); transform = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]; alpha = 0; opaque = NO; layer = (null)` ??

```
+ (void) getInitialCurrencyToDisplay:(NSString *)dbPath{


    AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

    if (sqlite3_open([dbPath UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK) {

        const char *sql = "select  c_name,C_Id from Currency";
        sqlite3_stmt *selectstmt;
        if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql, -1, &selectstmt, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {

            while(sqlite3_step(selectstmt) == SQLITE_ROW) {
                NSInteger primaryKey = sqlite3_column_int(selectstmt, 1);

                Currency *Obj = [[Currency alloc]initWithPrimaryKey:primaryKey];
                Obj.C_Name = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(selectstmt, 0)];
                Obj.address=[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(selectstmt, 1)];

                NSArray *documentPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
                NSString *documentsDir = [documentPaths objectAtIndex:0];
                NSLog(@"%@", documentsDir);
                NSString *pngFilePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@.png",documentsDir, Obj.C_Name];

                Obj.C_Image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:pngFilePath];


           Obj.isDirty = NO;
                [appDelegate.array addObject:Obj];

            }
        }
```

I used above code to get data from Database
Thanks in Advance

Comment: my guess: `Currency` is a subclass of `UIView` instead of `NSObject`

Comment: When you NSLog an NSArray all it does is output the starting and ending `()` characters and, in-between, invoke `description` for every object in the array.  So you have some objects in your array that produce that `description` output (presumably because they subclass UIView).  You can always override `description` to output (almost) whatever you want in classes you define.

Comment: @Matthias Bauch suprub thanks bro it solved my prob actually i'm struck in dis from 5 hours thaknks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the parent class of your `Currency` class. The parent class should be `NSObject` and not `UIView` or similar.

---

And please have a look at the [Objective-C naming conventions](http://cocoadevcentral.com/articles/000082.php). Only classes should start with a capital letter.

Answer (score 0):

By the looks of it your adding some empty views or something. Since you are adding "Obj" shouldn't you know what type of object it is? What are you even trying to do?

Comment: I want to load some contents from DataBase, I'll keep them in Object and i'll assign it to array, I want array values to display in UITableview

Comment: Ok... So again what are you loading from the database? NSString's? What type of database are you using? If you could post more code maybe I could help you.